# Display different list of "Custom Templates" for each Custom Page Type

Tags: templates

I was wondering if it is possible to categories Custom Page Templates. I would like to display 2 meta boxes which display different templates (which would then only be displayed on page edit screen if conditions are met.)

Edit: I am trying to separate my pages templates into groups. It's really for the sake of my site admins. They have a template drop down list populated with hundreds of templates (we are a marketing company and create lots of landing page / email creatives)

So for example custom page types:

'landing-page' would only display templates set to display for this post type

'email-creative' would display a separate list of templates

Comment: Categorized in which sense

Comment: So you want to show different metaboxes depending on the template the user selected?

Comment: Just in the sense of being able to separate page templates into different meta boxes.

For example, pages in the category of "landing-pages" should only display Templates within a 'landing-page' category.

Perhaps i'm confusing this by using the word category with templates

Comment: not exactly @fischi, I use ACF for conditional rules such as this. I am trying to separate my pages templates into groups.

It's really for the sake of my site admins. They have a template drop down list populated with hundreds of templates (we are a marketing company and create lots of landing page / email creatives)

Comment: Do you already have a list of the structured templates?

Comment: @James Please update your question with that info about the custom fields. This is definitely doable but is going to take a lot of coding though which I unfortunately don't have time for at this stage

Comment: @fischi If you mean I currently see all the templates in my template_dropdown() then you are correct.

Comment: @James okay, that's good - but do you have them already structured in your templatecategories? Or do you need a way to do that? I do not really know how far you are yet.

Comment: @fischi I have not heard of this so would be a no.